# While forwarding the rendering JS is not included in .xhtml

Tags: javascript, java, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm developing a Primefaces/JSF app.

In a bean, I'm forwarding the rendering to another page, not the one correspondent to the bean, using this script:

```
 FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context, null, "other-page.xhtml");
```

On `other-page.xhtml`some JS file will be not included, compromising page's rendering.

The strange thing is that if I point directly through the browser to `other-page.xhtml` the page is rendered in the right way.
Why?
How is it possible?

Why `handleNavigation` cause this problem? How can I resolve?

Using `.dispatch` or `.redirect` the problem doesn't appear, but I cannot use both methods for other reasons.

This is the page code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Challenge</title>
        <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="loginForm">


            <p:growl id="msg" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
            <p:panel header="CHALLENGE!!" style="width: 360px;">

                <h:panelGrid id="loginPanel" columns="2">

                    <h:outputText value="Username" />

                    <p:inputText id="username" value="#{challengeBean.username}" ></p:inputText>

                    <p:spacer></p:spacer>

                    <p:message for="username" ></p:message>

                    <h:outputText value="Password" />

                    <p:password id="password" value="#{challengeBean.password}"  feedback="false"></p:password>

                    <p:spacer></p:spacer>

                    <p:message for="password"></p:message>

                    <p:spacer></p:spacer>

                    <p:commandButton action="#{challengeBean.submit}" value="submit" update="submit" ajax="false"></p:commandButton>

                </h:panelGrid>

            </p:panel>

        </h:form>

    </h:body> 

</html>
```

Comment: Be carefull that some characters (such as '<' and '>') are not valid in jsp/jsf. It happened to me while doing a comparison.
Try puting the javascript in a different file and importing it.

Comment: I'm delegating all the imports to JSF/Primefaces using <h:head> tag, see edit answer for source code.

Comment: @BalusC Can you help me? Any idea in order to solve the problem? I know you are one of smartest guy in JSF. Thx